# NoProxy only for main domain - cntlm

Tags: ubuntu, firewall, proxy, curl, cntlm

I am running Ubuntu in a corporate firewall with cntlm.

For working with my local dev sites I have to insert then into the NoProxy like so `*.local`.

I have a problem with a site that I running locally and, almost every call to the server, calls another domain that needs a proxy authentication.

To  clarify:
Let's say I have a file `www.site.local/test.php`:

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $str);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
```

So when I call `www.site.local/test.php` I need it to be without the proxy, but for the curl in the file I need the proxy, for now I'm getting a timeout.

Is there a way to configure cntlm to exclude proxy only for the domain and not for the other calls?